# What is the hypernym of Earnings and Deduction?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

If **Earnings** means an item that adds value to any stack.  And, If **Deductions** means any item that subtracts value from any stack.

Then what single *<word>* can be an *either* Earning or Deduction?  As in:

- You will be Earning 200 this June.  (plus 200)
- You will be Deducted 100 this July.  (less 100)
- You will be *<word>* +500 this August.  (plus 500)
- You will be *<word>* -400 this September.  (less 400)

Comment: Your opening sentence brings to mind the famous quote about [how many legs a calf would have if you called its tail a leg](http://timpanogos.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/lincoln-quote-sourced-calfs-tail-not-dogs-tail/).  How are stacks relevant to pay data, and vice versa?

Comment: Perhaps it's as simple as *net*?   The hypernym might be something like *ledger entries* or *line-items* or *transactions* or *adjustments*, but *net* works in your example sentences since *net* simply refers to the resultant sum of all line-items-  After earnings of $100 and deductions of $75 you will be net +$25 this month.

Comment: Oh, I think I have misunderstood your question. I think you really don't want to go for a single word- use *credited* or *debited* as the case may be.  But you could always just use *credited* as, of course, a negative credit is a debit.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60707/accounting

Comment: possibly "line items" in certain senses.

Comment: sorry, Jim mentioned "line-items" already, good one

Comment: You don't lump opposite concepts into one word more complicated than "stuff" or "things"

Answer (score 0):

Some stock exchange information calls this the **change net**. You will need to, like the stock markets, say what your *net* is, for instance: change net (%).